# JScrollPane hides the textarea

Tags: java, jscrollpane

I can't figure out why this doesn't work... It hides the JTextArea.

```
JTextArea _area=new JTextArea();
_area.setBounds(10, 10, 465, 250);
add(_area);

JScrollPane scroller=new JScrollPane(_area);
scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
add(scroller);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Shuffle the bound values set the bounds only of `ScrollPane` and not of `TextArea`.

```
        JTextArea _area = new JTextArea();
//        _area.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 250);
        add(_area);

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(_area);
        scroller.setBounds(10, 10, 400, 250);
        scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        add(scroller);
```

Comment: I seted setLayout(null) on frame because I'm using setBounds() on my components.